# Find first item with alphabetical precedence in list with numbers

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

Say I have a list object occupied with both numbers and strings. If I want to retrieve the first string item with the highest alphabetical precedence, how would I do so?

Here is an example attempt which is clearly incorrect, but corrections as to what needs to be changed in order for it to achieve the desired result would be greatly appreciated:

```
lst = [12, 4, 2, 15, 3, 'ALLIGATOR', 'BEAR', 'ANTEATER', 'DOG', 'CAT']

lst.sort()
for i in lst:
   if i[0] == "A":
      answer = i
print(answer)
```

Comment: What about `sorted([i for i in lst if isinstance(i, str)])[0]`?

Comment: You can't sort this list in Python3 without filtering, as you can no longer compare `int` and `str` types

Answer (score 16):

First use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) to filter out non-strings, and then use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) to select the string with the highest alphabetical presence:

```
>>> min(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, str))
'ALLIGATOR
```

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, I don't know what you mean by "firstly converted to list"

Answer (score 8):

IIUC you could use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to get sublist of your original list with only strings, then with `sorted` get first element by alphabetical sorting:

```
sub_lst = [i for i in lst if isinstance(i, str)]
result = sorted(sub_lst)[0]


print(sub_lst)
['ALLIGATOR', 'BEAR', 'ANTEATER', 'DOG', 'CAT']

print(result)
'ALLIGATOR'
```

Or you could use `min` as @TigerhawkT3 suggested in the comment:

```
print(min(sub_lst))
'ALLIGATOR'
```

Comment: Or `min()` instead of `sorted()[0]`.

Comment: Note: materializing the list (necessary for sorting) requires O(N) space and then sorting requires O((N log N) comparisons. On the other hand, using `min` on a generator expression only requires O(1) space and O(N) comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to filter the main list `lst` from intergers using `filter` built-in method:

```
>>> min(filter(lambda s:isinstance(s, str), lst))
'ALLIGATOR'
```